# Weighted average: Variable weight list based on data length

Tags: math

I'm struggling with what seems like it should be a simple and straightforward calculation. I'm trying to produce a weighted average of a list, where the most recent elements heavier than the earlier ones. The weighting list needs to be based on the length of the input list and add up to 1.

Let's say I have a given list:
`l = [123, 456, 789]`

Next step is to make a weight list, something like this (I just made these numbers up, but they show the general idea of the weight profile I'm after):
`w = [0.15, 0.25, 0.6]`

This is where I'm stuck. Generating `w` based on the length of `l`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the weights you're looking after are somewhat like:

[a, 2a, 3a, 4a, ...,n*a]

Sum of weights: (a*n*(n+1))/2 = 1

Solve for a and fill your weight array.

When N is 3, a would be (1/6)

w = [1/6, 2/6, 3/6]

Comment: Precisely what I'm looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Great.! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow some sort of monotonically increasing function (i.e. `e^x`) and just normalize the first `n` values where `n` is the length of the list.